# How to update all the documents in a collection with the default values if Schema got changed in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Schema like this before

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
});
```

Now my Schema got changed

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    name: String,
    content: {
        title: {type: String, default: 'Some Title'},
        description: {type: String, default: 'Some Description'}
    }
});
```

Now that the Schema has changed , I want to update the previous documents in the collection with the dafault values , how to do it?

Comment: Yeah it worked , Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute following [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) query directly on MongoDB shell

```
db.collectionName.updateMany({}, {$set: {
    content: {title: "Some title", description: "Some description"}
}})
```

The first parameter to update is an empty object, which matches to all existing records.

Comment: what if I wanted to do something like $set: {
        field1:
          transfоrmFunc("$field2.subfield") ||
          transfоrmFunc("$field2.subfield1")
      } ?